# Can’t set up my Alcatel tablet through Google

Tags: google-account, 2fa, alcatel

I recently decided to use my Alcatel tablet but forgot the password to unlock the tablet, so I did a hard reset to factory settings which worked successfully. My issue is that I’m stuck on the 2-step verification.

No matter how many times I put my email, password, and allow verification through my second device, it keeps coming back asking me for my email, password and again to approve verification through the second device, only to go back asking me again the same thing. I’ve tried through text and email still stuck.

Please help

Comment: What is the tablet model name? And what Android version is installed?